# Error: std::bad_alloc for no apparent reason

Tags: r, for-loop, memory-leaks, allocation, bad-alloc

I've got the `Error: std::bad_alloc` error when trying to use a for loop:

`trees <- as.multiPhylo(for ( i in 1:100 ) { rand_tip(my.input, tree, forceultrametric = TRUE, prune = FALSE) })`

The weird thing is, I used the rand_tip function before without any problem, then I tried this loop and got this error, and then I tested the function without the loop and got the same error! I'm pretty sure this is not a memory problem.

Does anybody know what's going on?

I'm editing a phylogenetic tree (object class LargePhylo) by adding missing species on it (using the rand_tip function). I used this function to do it before and it worked well. But now I need to do it many times, so I used the loop. After using it I receive the message that the function start to work (as normally) but then I got this `std::bad_alloc` error.

```
> trees <- as.multiPhylo(for ( i in 1:100 ) {
+   rand_tip(my.input, tree, forceultrametric = TRUE, prune = FALSE)
+ })
***************************************************************
*                          Note:                              *
*    force.ultrametric does not include a formal method to    *
*    ultrametricize a tree & should only be used to coerce    *
*   a phylogeny that fails is.ultramtric due to rounding --   *
*    not as a substitute for formal rate-smoothing methods.   *
***************************************************************
Error: std::bad_alloc
```

When trying to run the function again, without the loop, I keep receiving the same error.

```
> new.tree <- rand_tip(my.input, tree, forceultrametric = TRUE, prune = FALSE)
***************************************************************
*                          Note:                              *
*    force.ultrametric does not include a formal method to    *
*    ultrametricize a tree & should only be used to coerce    *
*   a phylogeny that fails is.ultramtric due to rounding --   *
*    not as a substitute for formal rate-smoothing methods.   *
***************************************************************
Error: std::bad_alloc
```